# Чем можно восстановить битый HDD в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hdd, раздел

Чем можно поковырять информацию в битом hdd? Диск не открывается, разделы видны - подсоединены как дополнительные к рабочей Linux системе. На самом битом диске раньше стоял windows, если это важно :)
Хотелось бы вытащить хотя-бы часть информации.
Интересуют именно варианты для Linux, в частности - ubuntu.

Comment: gpart, photorec. Но лучше несите к профессионалам.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Интересуют именно методы собственными силами)

Comment: Если диск имеет механические повреждения (например, из-за резкого удара головка процарапала поверхность блина), дальнейшая работа с ним приведёт к ухудшению ситуации и, как результат, полному отказу диска и потере всех данных (на примере с царапиной — головка, проходя над ней, мало того что будет сдирать шероховатости, раскидывая абразивную пыль по всему блину, так ещё и сама будет обдираться и деформироваться, рискуя в очередной раз коснуться блина, благо бешеные скорости вращения диска способствуют).

Answer (score 4):

Сначала хорошо бы снять дамп прогой `ddrescue`. И потом уже в спокойно ковырять образ.

А вот держать на питании просто так битый диск - вообще ужасная идея. Если он умирает по механие\электронике, то чем меньше его дёргать - тем выше вероятность вытащить инфу.

Из софта для восстановления, помиимо `photorec`, как написал @Владимир-Мартьянов можно ещё попробовать `testdisk`. Из виндового - сильно помогал `R-Studio` и `Active@ File Recovery`.

Ещё тут [хорошо](http://habrahabr.ru/post/56796/) написано.

Answer (score 1):

Команда `sudo fsck -p /dev/sdxX` проверит раздел `/dev/sdxX` (например, `/dev/sda1`) на наличие ошибок.

UPD: опять сделал очепятку в 'fsck'