# Восстановление данных с lvm2

Tags: linux, lvm

Доброго времени суток. Ситуация следующая, был у нас сервак, работал он на linux, файловая система lvm2. Физически было там три диска, один под систему, другие два были в зеркале(mirrored) под данные. В один прекрасный день сервак пал, умер диск с системой, а на дисках в зеркале остались важные данные. Подскажите, как можно восстановить данные, какие есть пути? можно ли из винды как-то его открыть? P.S. Новый сервак тоже на linux lvm, может как-то к нему можно примонтировать диски, чтобы не потерять данные.

Answer (score 1):

> Подскажите, как можно восстановить данные, какие есть пути?

примонтировать и скопировать:

```
# mount что-монтировать куда-монтировать
# cp -a что-копировать куда-копировать
```

> можно ли из винды как-то его открыть?

судя по ответам к этому, например, [вопросу](https://askubuntu.com/q/60240/416190), теоретически возможно, а на практике, я подозреваю, процесс будет аналогичен надеванию штанов через голову.

---

и вообще, судя по уровню компетенции, отражённой в вопросе, вам имеет смысл обратиться к специалистам.

Comment: Попробую переформулировать вопрос на сколько я его понимаю. Раньше была группа томов, состоящая из трех физических томов. Два из них,которые в зеркале, были одним из логических томов. Я хочу примонтировать один из этих дисков к новому серверу, т.е добавить его в новую группу томов. И при этом хочу не потерять данные. Иными словами, вопрос в том, есть ли какие-нибудь нюансы при монтировании, ведь старый сервер просто умер и никаких подготовительных действий к переносу не было. Да, я далеко не сисадмин, но я пытаюсь разобраться. Неужели, перенос диска с данными такая сложная операция.

Comment: @Totoro, я совершенно не против того, чтобы кто-нибудь оказал вам бесплатную многочасовую (а, скорее, многодневную) консультацию по восстановлению наполовину утраченных данных, хотя данный ресурс и абсолютно не приспособлен к подобному. а у меня, к сожалению, на это нет ни времени, ни желания.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Возможно я ввел вас в заблуждение словом "восстанавливать". На сколько я понимаю, данные целые и два моих диска, которые были в зеркале - тоже целые. Их нужно просто добавить в новый сервер. В виндоус такая операция заняла бы минуту. Неужели все так сложно? Хотя, возможно, я слишком многое не понимаю.

Comment: @Totoro, похожий вопрос уже задавался: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/457156/191416 . Напишу ещё раз. Сначала откатай полные копии винтов, а потом присоединяй куда и как хочешь. Если не будет получаться - у тебя будет бэкап. А так - да, или специалисты и за деньги. Или сам, но с ненулевой вероятностью потерять данные. Но бэкап всё равно сделай - вдруг винты при 3-м старте тоже двинут кони.