# Что делать, если произошли ошибки во время изменения структуры жд?

Tags: linux, windows, файловая-система

При помощи acronis disk director (для windows) поменял жесткий диск с динамического на базовый. Машина перезагрузилась и на середине процесса выдала `suberror... Press any key to reboot`. После перезагрузки выводится сообщение `reboot and select proper boot device`.

Я попробовал загрузится в линукс с флешки, там `GParted` показывает мой жесткий диск как сплошное неразмеченное пространство. Есть ли шанс восстановить все как было?
И из-за чего могла произойти ошибка?

_

Вопрос не совсем по программированию, но ведь нет русскоязычного askubuntu/более подходящих по тематике сайтов.

Comment: а бэкап машины есть?

Comment: @Mikhail, конечно нет.

Comment: Есть ответ: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457232/191416

Comment: @donRumata, там ситуация другая, у меня даже разделы не видны. В GParted отображается просто "неразмеченное пространство".

Comment: @LNK, сразу видно, что ты прочёл, но не сделал как я написал в том ответе. "Видишь суслика? И я нет, а он есть". Gparted не должен показывать удалённые разделы - это не его задача. Его задача работать с существующими или создавать новые. Работа с *удалёнными* разделами - задача программ для восстановления. Угадай где перечислен рабочий софт.

Answer (score 0):

GParted может показывать диск неразмеченным в случае,если у вас слетел Boot - собственно ваш случай.
Восстанавливайте  загрузчик,есть шанс сохранить данные.

Comment: http://remontka.pro/select-proper-boot-device/
собственно вот,как я и описал

Comment: у меня при команде` bootrec /fixboot` пишет "Элемент не найден". И в первом окне не выводится моя система...

Comment: Кроме того, команда` bootrec /scanos ` пишет обнаружено 0 систем windows.