# Как восстановить удалённые файлы в отдельном каталоге логического раздела?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, файлы, восстановление

Допустим в папке `dir` у меня лежали два файла `file1.msk` и `file2.msk`, которые были удалены командой `rm`. Существует ли способ восстановить только их (или все файлы в папке), но не весь логический раздел? И если да, то какой?

Comment: Есть такой шуточный ответ -- "... очень просто, восстановите их из бэкапа. -- А у меня нет бэкапа. -- Значит эти файлы вам на самом деле не нужны."

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/457232/191416

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Существует ли способ восстановить

Это зависит от файловой системы. Насколько я помню, для ext2 были какие-то утилитки, для ext3 - уже нет. Чем сложнее устроена ФС, тем меньше шансов восстановить хоть что-то. Почитайте вот это:

http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/file-sys/vosstanovlenie-failov-v-Linux.html

может быть - поможет!